# MySQL WHERE clause link to another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Table A contains (amongst others) two columns X1 and Y1. Table B contains (amongst others) X2 and Y2.

I am trying to create a SELECT query on table A where only elements are returned if X1,Y1 match an entry X2,Y2 in table B but I am struggling a bit with it.

I am trying something along the lines of

`SELECT * FROM A WHERE CONCAT(X1, X2) IN (SELECT CONCAT(X2, Y2) FROM B)`

This seems to work, but I can't wonder if this is correct. Should I perhaps use some sort of join on the tables?

Comment: I would go with join making sure there are indexes on x and y in both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
JOIN B ON (A.X1, A.Y1) = (B.X2, B.Y2)
```

or

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.X1 = B.X2
      AND A.Y1 = B.Y2
```

If `B(X2, Y2)` is not unique, additional DISTINCT needed for duplicates remove.

Comment: Both options seem to give the same sort of performance (in my case) .. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Lieuwe *Both options seem to give the same sort of performance (in my case)* Of course - they are synonims.